# Counting distinct elements in smallest number of queries

Tags: computational-complexity

There is an array of objects $a_1, \dots, a_n$. For any two objects, we can ask if they're equal or not. Our goal is to find the number of distinct objects in the array by only asking such queries. Assuming that the total number of distinct objects is $k$, it is possible to do so in $O(nk)$ by simply comparing each object against any other, unless it's equal to some object that we found earlier.

Is it possible to improve this estimation asymptotically, possibly using randomized algorithms?

Comment: I don't think a deterministic algorithm can do better than $O(nk)$.  Every object has to be compared at least once to each of the $k$ types, otherwise we don't know if it is a new type.

Comment: We're not allowed to hash the objects (etc), only test equality?

Comment: Yes, let's assume a very general case when we can only test equality.